# While reading a file. How can you know that you are reading the last item of a related serie?

Tags: java

I have a coding challenge in Java.
In reading a text file. (Nice fix length file)
Several lines make up an item. 
But several item can be related to the same subject. The items (sections of lines) are distributed over the file.
Now while readlining in Java and building my items. (Already doing that, so not a question.) I need to know whether that specific item is the last item related to a specific subject. (I need to know whether more items are coming or not.)

Does anyone have an elegant solution to this problem. 
(Putting them all in memory is an issue. The files an be GB's big.)
I could write all records to a database. But I want to avoid the overhead associated with writing and reading to an sql DB.

Comment: It's not possible to answer your question without seeing the specifics of the format of your file.

Comment: if you don't know how many items there are, and if you can't tell it's the last by looking at it, you'll have to read the whole file. One way could be start by splitting the file among other files, one per subject, then process those files one after the other

Answer (score 0):

With a simple pass: no.

Reading the file twice gives you a bunch of options:

- First pass sorts the items by section, second pass reads in orders
- First pass counts the items per section, second pass then knows how many items to expect per section
- Probably a bunch more.

Comment: Extremely inefficient. Proper format standardizations with delimiters could do it in a single pass, and would be much better.

Comment: Well, I assumed the format is given. Obviously if you have control over the format, you can do a lot more.

Comment: Hello everybody, thank you for thinking with me. The format is existing and a reality I have to live with. But I think I have to agree with Zeiss that a double pass is likely the best solution. And likely to out perform the writing and reading to an sqldb. Even though the idea of reading the same file twice isn't appealing.  I hoped someone knew a better solution, but sometimes things can't be done more elegant.